# How to change compact fluorescent 4 pin bulb at 22 feet

Tags: replacement, bulb

I have compact fluorescent 4 pin bulbs that in the ceiling at 22 feet. I cannot find any bulb changing tools which I can use to reach the height using a pole. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

(As a side note: Running out of luck finding a rental place that has 18 foot ladder. )

Comment: If you can't rent a ladder, rent staging. And strongly consider replacing the fixture with an LED fixture while you have it, which should give you 50,000 hours before the next time.

Comment: Any way to make an extension ladder work?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on replacement with an LED light. I looked on 1000bulbs.com and bulbs.com as well as HomeDepot and Lowes. None have a LED bulb which replaces this 4 pin base (GX24q-3). Using an adapter to convert the base does not work either since the ballast would need to be bypassed.

Comment: Personally, I would simply not use them. I am of the (humble) opinion that having lights that high in a residence is flat out foolish, and you are experiencing why right now, ESPECIALLY with proprietary CFLs.
Unless you can afford to hire someone every time a lamp burns out of course, and with 22' ceilings I bet this is likely.

Comment: Sounds like the perfect excuse to buy yourself a drone

Comment: Rent a boom lift, once, and swap that fixture for one which is appropriate for the location.  HID ballasts fail too, so stick an Edison E27 base there, and put **no bulb** there.  Then, **from the ground** using a common bulb-changer stick, install a modern LED "bulb".  *Do not install the first bulb from the boom lift. Force yourself to install it from the ground*. That way, you don't accidentally stick a bulb up there that can't be removed from the ground.

Answer (score 3):

*What were they thinking?*  I'll tell you exactly: "the last guy" installed that bulb from a boom lift or the top of the ladder and declared mission accomplished. *Never thought about the feasibility of changing it from the ground in the future*.

### Rent a boom lift and change that fixture

Select one that has an Edison base aiming straight down, and that has a big enough hole in the shade that it can be reached.  And then, **put no bulb in it** and come down to the ground.

Then, **from the ground** using a common bulb-changer stick, install a modern LED "bulb".   *Do not install the first bulb from the boom lift; that was the last guy's mistake!*

If this just doesn't work out with that fixture, then take it down and put up another fixture that does, while you still have the boom lift.

Answer (score 1):

There are definitely bulb-grasping heads that fit standard pole threads, and section or extension poles which reach that far. Whether one can actually manipulate a bulb well enough at that distance,  I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I purchased this on eBay. Hopefully, you can too.

Comment: It would help the OP if there were some pictures of how to use this item and a description of it.